# Spark map dataframe to array

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with the Spark MLlib PrefixSpan algorithm. I had some code working in Spark 1.6, but we recently moved to Spark 2.2.

I have a dataframe like this

```
viewsPurchasesGrouped: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [session_id: decimal(29,0), view_product_ids: array<bigint> ... 1 more field]

root
 |-- session_id: decimal(29,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- view_product_ids: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- purchase_product_ids: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

and in Spark 1.6, I used this piece of code to convert it to the appropriate dataframe for MLlib consumption:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray

val viewsPurchasesRddString = viewsPurchasesGrouped.map( row =>
  Array(
    Array(row.getAs[WrappedArray[String]](1).toArray), 
    Array(row.getAs[WrappedArray[String]](2).toArray)
  )
)
```

Since our switch, this doesn't work anymore.

I've tried this:

```
val viewsPurchasesRddString2 = viewsPurchasesGrouped.select("view_product_ids","purchase_product_ids").rdd.map( row =>
  Array(
    row.getSeq[Long](0).toArray, 
    row.getSeq[Long](1).toArray
  )
)
```

and see this baffling error message, which means that it took session_id and purchase_product_ids instead of view_product_ids and purchase_product_ids out of the original dataframe.

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: [...] scala.MatchError: [14545234113341303814564569524,WrappedArray(123, 234, 456, 678, 789)]
```

I've also tried this:

```
val viewsPurchasesRddString = viewsPurchasesGrouped.map {
   case Row(session_id: Long, view_product_ids: Array[Long], purchase_product_ids: Array[Long]) => 
     (view_product_ids, purchase_product_ids)
}
```

which fails with

```
viewsPurchasesRddString: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Array[Long], Array[Long])] = [_1: array<bigint>, _2: array<bigint>]
prefixSpan: org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.PrefixSpan = org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.PrefixSpan@10d69876
<console>:67: error: overloaded method value run with alternatives:
  [Item, Itemset <: Iterable[Item], Sequence <: Iterable[Itemset]](data: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[Sequence])org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.PrefixSpanModel[Item] <and>
  [Item](data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Array[Item]]])(implicit evidence$1: 
scala.reflect.ClassTag[Item])org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.PrefixSpanModel[Item] cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Array[Long], Array[Long])])
   val model = prefixSpan.run(viewsPurchasesRddString)
                          ^
```

How do I port my code correctly?

Comment: It's hard to answer without having the data schema and more context. Ideally, you could hand us a notebook with data and runnable code (appreciated but not expected)

Comment: @StevenBlack Thanks for your answer. I have added the schema of viewsPurchasesGrouped. There isn't much more context, except the origin of viewsPurchasesGrouped, which is a Hive table. If you can point me to a resource for how to make a notebook that is independent from the Hive table, but still contains data with the same schema, I will also gladly provide a working notebook!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your dataframe suggests that the columns are of type `array<string>`, so you should not access these using `Seq[Long]`. In spark 1.6, `map` on a dataframe automatically switched to RDD API, in Spark 2 you need to use `rdd.map` instead to do the same thing. So I would suggest this should work:

```
val viewsPurchasesRddString = viewsPurchasesGrouped.rdd.map( row =>
  Array(
    Array(row.getAs[WrappedArray[String]](1).toArray), 
    Array(row.getAs[WrappedArray[String]](2).toArray)
  )
)
```

Comment: I just realized that it did say Array[String], this was copied from a wrong place. I just fixed it!

Comment: Your version works! This is the adapted code:

val viewsPurchasesRddString = viewsPurchasesGrouped.rdd.map( row =>
  Array(
    Array(row.getAs[WrappedArray[Long]](1).toArray), 
    Array(row.getAs[WrappedArray[Long]](2).toArray)
  )
)

It also works like this: 

val viewsPurchasesRddString = viewsPurchasesGrouped.rdd.map( row =>
  Array(
    row.getAs[WrappedArray[Long]](1).toArray, 
    row.getAs[WrappedArray[Long]](2).toArray
  )
)